# passing an array to a function formal parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have some doubts regarding pointers and arrays.Please correct me wherever i am wrong.

1)
i have read on the net that there are two ways of passing an array to a function.One in which,the formal parameter of the function is an array,like int a[]
and the second,in which the formal parameter is a pointer like int *a
But have a look here.In the below code,the first technique of passing arrays has been used.But I dont understand why we have passed balance as the actual parameter.I have read that for the array balance[],it's name,that is "balance" is a constant pointer to the first element.So,the value of  balance is the address of the first element(and *balance would be the first element of the array).

It would have been fine had the formal parameter been a pointer,because in that case,the address would have been assigned as the value of the formal parameter pointer.
I don't get why we have an array as a formal parameter and an address as an actual parameter (argument)?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration */
double getAverage(int arr[], int size);

int main ()
{
    /* an int array with 5 elements */
  int balance[5] = {1000, 2, 3, 17, 50};
  double avg;

  /* pass pointer to the array as an argument */
  avg = getAverage( balance, 5 ) ;

 /* output the returned value */
  printf( "Average value is: %f ", avg );

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double getAverage(int arr[], int size);` and `double getAverage(int *arr, int size);` are *exactly* the same/equivalent.

Comment: yups! got that !:)Where did you learn this stuff?

Answer (score 4):

Declaring a formal parameter like this

```
double getAverage(int arr1[], int size);
//                        ^^
```

is the same as declaring it like this:

```
double getAverage(int *arr2, int size);
//                    ^
```

The compiler interprets these two declarations in the same way: it allows dereferencing `arr1` as if it were a pointer, and of course it allows to apply square brackets operator to `arr2` because square brackets works with all pointers, as well as with arrays.

Passing `balance` can be done in two ways as well: you can pass it the way you do in your code snippet

```
avg = getAverage( balance, 5 );
```

or like a pointer to the initial element:

```
avg = getAverage( &balance[0], 5 );
```

Again, both invocations are identical to each other.

Comment: hey i didnt know that the compiler interprets arr1[] as a pointer.I knew about the decay thing though.Where do you get to learn this stuff?I mean i am sure there is no exhaustive resource for c language on google.I just keep switching from one tutorial to another.Is there some book you read where you get to learn this kind of stuff?Thanx a lot for everything !

Comment: @garfield Pretty much everything that I know about C language I learned from [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). The relatively tiny book covers the language end-to-end, so I highly recommend reading the book and doing all the exercises in it.

Comment: i will definitely read that book! I covered let us c.Its by some Indian author.It didnt cover all the concepts. :P Thanx a ton :DGod bless you

Comment: Sorry, both invocations are not exactly identical, as the first is a pointer to the whole array (and so, the sizeof operator applied to the pointed thing is the size of the array) but the second means a pointer to the first element (and it's sizeof operator gives the size of the array element)  Despite of this, as both are passed as pointer to int, finally, there's no way to get the array size from inside the function body (that's the reason of passing the number of elements as a parameter)

Comment: @LuisColorado How is `sizeof` operator even relevant here? I am talking about invoking a function, and `sizeof` operator is definitely *not* a function.

Comment: ok, it's not relevant, but it makes both expressions somewhat different in behaviour, not what you said.  (*almost identical* would be nice for me)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get why we have an array as a formal parameter and an address as an actual parameter (argument)?

As a function parameter, `int arr[]`, is equivalent to `int *arr`. So when you declare your function as

```
 double getAverage(int arr[], int size);
```

compiler interprets it as

```
 double getAverage(int *arr, int size);
```

That means, function `getAverage` expects its first argument is of type pointer to `int` (`int *`), not an array of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

double getAverage (int *arr, int size);

int main (void) {
    double avg;
    int balance [5]={1000, 2, 3, 17, 50};
    int *ptr;
    ptr = balance;
    avg= getAverage(ptr,5);
    printf("Average of the array is %f", avg);
    return 0;   
}

double getAverage (int *arr, int size) {
    int i;
    double sum=0.0;
    double avg=0.0;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        sum += *arr;
        arr = arr+1;
    }
    avg = (sum/size);
    return avg;
}
```